# join table and filter and take aggregrate function sql access

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2007

Is it possible to join two tables,filter the data and take aggregate function in MS access? I have two tables

```
Inv_details:invnum,itmcde,qnt,price  
Inv_summary:invnum,date,total
```

I need to join this tables and filter them with date range and have sum of qnt and price order by itmcde.

I tried something like this.

```
SELECT inv.itmcde,SUM(inv.qnt),SUM(inv.price) FROM (SELECT inv_s.invnum,inv_s.date,inv_d.itmcde,inv_d.total FROM Inv_summary as inv_s INNER JOIN Invoice_details as inv_d ON inv_d.invnum =inv_s.invNum WHERE inv_s.date BETWEEN  #3/4/2013# And #5/16/2013# ) as inv ORDER BY inv.itmcde
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT d.itmcde,
       SUM(d.qnt) AS qnt,
       SUM(d.price) AS price
  FROM Inv_summary s INNER JOIN Inv_details d 
    ON d.invnum = s.invnum 
 WHERE s.date BETWEEN #3/4/2013# AND #5/16/2013# 
 GROUP BY d.itmcde
 ORDER BY d.itmcde
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ce28/4)** *Although this fiddle is for SQL Server same general rules should apply in MS Access*

Comment: i tried this and having same error `You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression itmcde as part of an aggregate function` In Inv_details i am having Composite Primary Key (invnum,itmcde).Please help me in advance

Comment: @Ravi See updated answer and also provided sqlfiddle to show haw it works. Although this fiddle is for SQL Server same general rules should apply in MS Access.